# (Help) APK Decomplied unreadable .pngs

Tags: decompilation, apk, decompile

I decompiled an Android game APK to look at the source code / resources and the .pngs give me the error "It looks like we don't support this file format" when I try to view them in the Photos App. I've tried decompiling with Apktool and just changing the extension to .zip but still no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to use a different image editor? looks like it is a codec problem